# Sessions Not working on Elastic beanstalk (Docker Compose Platform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have deployed my django application on Beanstalk on docker compose platform with application load balancer and autoscaling group. I can see my application on the expected domain and it is working fine but when i login to it - it says 'login successful' but redirects to login page again. It keeps doing that and I am unable to solve this error for days. EC2 instance logs are clear and without errors, container logs donot have any error too. Also My target group is unhealthy and elastic beanstalk keeps saying:

'Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.'

I am expecting OK health on my beanstalk environment and healthy target group. Also This session problem should be solved and i should redirect to my dashboard after login in to my website.

[Here is my Target group health](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QClm.png)
[This is my load balancer configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrU4d.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have solved the issue the problem wa swith environment variable i was adddng DEBUG=True which was for local only.
Thanks for your time I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the environment variable in my case. The environment variable DEBU=True was creating a session issue because this env variable is for local only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).